# trouble understanding C pointer in the following

Tags: c

I have the following function:

```
int do_something(...,const float writeArray[],...){
printf("%d",*writeArray);
return 0;
}
```

how I use this function is:

```
do_something(...,&data[0],...);
```

where data[0]=1

obviously my code isn't as simple as this, but this is an illustration of the problem. When I run do_something, I get a printf value of a very large number like 23259894325. What am I doing wrong? How should I make it printf 1 like its supposed to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("%d",*writeArray);
```

First off, you're printing the first element of the array in a really weird way. If you want to do that, do `writeArray[0]` so other people can read your code.

Second, `%d` is for print integers, but `writeArray` is full of floats. Try using `%f`. You need to use [the right format string for each type](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/).

```
do_something(...,&data[0],...);
```

This is really confusing. You want a pointer to the first element of the array? Or you're just trying to pass the entire array? If you want to pass the array (like your later function signature suggests), just do this:

```
do_something(...,data,...);
```

Arrays turn into pointers when you pass them to functions anyway.

If you really do want a pointer, change your second function signature to show that:

```
int do_something(...,const float *writeArray,...){
```

Comment: ah that makes sense, I guess I;m too dependent on the compiler to scream at me for these kind of things...

Comment: @mugetsu - I strongly advise learning what the compiler warnings mean rather than blindly following them.

Comment: @mugetsu: Using `%d` is not an error. It just does not achieve what you want. There is a difference.

Comment: as for the strange way I dealt with do_something(..., &data[0],...), this is something in someone else's code. I'm not too familiar with c so it confused me as well, probably the reason why I was not thinking that I was misprinting my data. I'm not quite too sure what the point is of it either :/

Answer (score 1):

`%d` specifies an signed integer. Use `%f` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing a float in,  your printf is trying to print an int